# Trying to delete from database using HTTPDELETE does nothing

Tags: c#, api

I am learning to code in c# and I am developing an API application. My GET method works but I have issues with my DELETE, it returns a success code(200) but it does not delete from my database which is connected to my application. I am using the unit of work and repository patterns and my code is as follows:

Controller code:

```
        private readonly IOrderService _orderService;

        public OrdersController(IOrderService orderService)
        {
            _orderService = orderService;         
        }

[HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> RemoveOrder(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                await _orderService.Delete(id);
                return StatusCode(200);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500);
            }

        }
```

Service Interface

```
public interface IOrderService
    {
        Task<Order> Get(int id);
        Task Add(Order order);
        Task Delete(int id);
        Task Update(int id, Order order);

        Task<IEnumerable<Order>> GetAllOrdersAsync();
        Task<IEnumerable<OrderDTO>> GetOrdersToCityAsync(string cityName);

        Task<OrderDTO> GetEmployeeOrdersToCountryAsync
    (
    string countryName, string employeeLastName
    );
    }
```

Service class:

```
 public class OrderService : IOrderService
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        public OrderService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }
        public async Task Delete(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                var order = await _unitOfWork.OrderRepository.Get(id);
                _unitOfWork.OrderRepository.Delete(order);
                await _unitOfWork.CommitAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                await _unitOfWork.RollbackAsync();
                throw;
            }
            
        }
}
```

Unit of work class:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private readonly NorthwindContext _db;
        private List<object> _customRepositories = new List<object>();
        private IProductRepository _productRepository;
        private IOrderRepository _orderRepository;
        public UnitOfWork(
            NorthwindContext db, 
            IProductRepository ProductRepository,
            IOrderRepository orderRepository
            )
        { 
            _db = db;
            _productRepository = ProductRepository;
            _orderRepository = orderRepository;
        }
```

uow interface:

```
    public interface IUnitOfWork
    {
        IProductRepository ProductRepository { get; }

        IOrderRepository OrderRepository { get; }
        Task CommitAsync();
        Task RollbackAsync();
    }
```

Order repository interface which extends my genericRepository:

```
    public interface IOrderRepository : IGenericRepository<Order>
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<OrderDTO>> GetOrdersToCityAsync(string cityName);

        Task<OrderDTO> GetEmployeeOrdersToCountryAsync
            (
            string countryName, string employeeLastName
            );
    }
```

Order repository:

```
   public class OrderRepository : GenericRepository<Order>, IOrderRepository
    {
        private readonly NorthwindContext _northwindContext;
        public OrderRepository(NorthwindContext db) : base(db)
        {
            _northwindContext = db;
        }
```

generic repository:

```
    public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        protected readonly NorthwindContext _db;

        public GenericRepository(NorthwindContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }


        public void Delete(T entity)
        {
            _db.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
        }
```

Please ignore if the curly braces are not closed properly, in my application they are.

Comment: What type of database?  If SQL Server use SQL Server Management Studio and in explorer under management check log files.  The server isn't checking if rows were actually deleted so the response you are getting is just a normal 200.  You need to debug the server to find issue.

Comment: MySQL workbench, regular sql

Comment: The default location for each of the logs is the MySQL Data directory (C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server [version number]\Data\), and the default log

Comment: My suggestion checking the logs probably solved issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following items:

- Unit of work implementation calls *SaveChanges()* on *CommitAsync* implementation.
- *NorthwindContext* object instance passed to repositories is the same instance as the one injected into UnitOfWork class. Otherwise you'll be working in different transactions.

Comment: Ok, I changed the name of the object NortwindContext from _northwindContext to _db and now I get an exception in my Delete method from the OrderService class. It says "an error occured when saving the entity changes"

Comment: Does it give you more information under InnerException property on the Exception?

Comment: Just checked and it seems that a foreign key constraint fails so I need to delete other stuff first. I think this was the answer so I check your reply. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could delete an entry from database while using the following code.

```
    [HttpDelete{"id"}]
    Public async<Task<ActionResult>> DeleteItem (int id)
    { try{
    Var itemToDelete = await UnitofWork.OrderRepository.GetAsync(id);
    If (Id!= null) {
    await Orderservice.Delete(itemToDelete);
    var result  = await UnitofWork.SaveChangesAsync();
    If (result) return StatusCode(200);
    Else return BadRequest();
    return ok(itemToDelete);
    } catch(exception ex) {
Throw new Error("Problem while deleting!");
}
    Return BadRequest();
    }
    }
```

Just check if the item you would want ro delete is null or not. Then attempt to delete it from database. Hoping it would give you an idea.